# How to remap 3 numpad keys to run control panel in autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to remap a combination of the following keys on the numpad
- Addition
- Minus
- Home

To open the control panel. However, AHK keep telling me "Error: Invalid hotkey"

My current code is as follows

```
~NumpadAdd & NumpadSub & NumpadHome::Run, Control
```

Answer (score 2):

[Hotkeys:Custom Combinations](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo)

> Combinations of three or more keys are not supported. Combinations
>   which your keyboard hardware supports can usually be detected by using
>   If and GetKeyState(), but the results may be inconsistent.

Try this:

```
#if GetKeyState("NumpadAdd", "P")
NumpadSub & Numpad7::Run Control
```